# eclipse gdb steps to previous line with -O2 flag

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, g++, eclipse-cdt

Step over occationally steps to previous line using gdb with both -g and -O2 flags. Remove the -O2 flags and it works as expected. Can anyone explain why that happens ?

I'm new to gdb in eclipse CDT and use it on C++ code with "Standard create process launcher".

Is this expected behaviour or is there a solution leaving optimization in ?

Answer (score 2):

It's expected.  The compiler will feel free to re-order code on higher optimization levels.  The man page even says that:

> "Without any optimization option, the
>   compiler's goal is to reduce the cost
>   of compilation and to make debugging
>   produce the expected results."

That goal has to fall by the wayside at higher levels.

Answer (score 2):

Optimization may re-arrange your code in sometimes unexpected ways. The debug information in the optimized code will have followed those re-arrangements around.

Answer (score 2):

There are no requirements that the code is executed exactly in the order you have written it, just that the result, "the observable behavior", is the same as-if it did.

§1.9:

> The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:
>
> — Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
>   — At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to one of the possible results that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
>   — The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.
>
> These collectively are referred to as the observable behavior of the program.